# Convert table to array in JavaScript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to convert the table grid i created into an multidimensional array according to the content inside the table. Array would be in format like:

```
 var array = [
               [column,column,...],
               [column,column,...],
               ...
              ];
```

How do I do this without using jQuery, using plain JavaScript? All answers I found was in jQuery.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lorp9sgn/10/).

Comment: It's probably not very difficult, what does the table grid look like?

Comment: its in the fiddle link above.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With qSA and `Array.prototype.map` is pretty simple.

```
var tableInfo = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tableId tr'), function(tr){
  return Array.prototype.map.call(tr.querySelectorAll('td'), function(td){
    return td.innerHTML;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Ah yes, map is a natural. Why did I go for reduce? ;-)

Comment: I do that a lot, always thinking in terms of reduce then I realize... "oh..."

Answer (score 7):

Presuming your table is something like the one below, you can convert that into an array of arrays using the *rows* collection of the table and *cells* collection of the rows:

```js
function tableToArray(table) {
  var result = []
  var rows = table.rows;
  var cells, t;

  // Iterate over rows
  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    t = [];

    // Iterate over cells
    for (var j=0, jLen=cells.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      t.push(cells[j].textContent);
    }
    result.push(t);
  }
  return result; 
}
    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(tableToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0])));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one<td>two<td>three
  <tr>
    <td>one<td>two<td>three
  <tr>
    <td>one<td>two<td>three
</table>
```

Or if like concise code, use some ES5 goodness:

```
function tableToArray(table) {
  var result  = [].reduce.call(table.rows, function (result, row) {
      result.push([].reduce.call(row.cells, function(res, cell) {
          res.push(cell.textContent);
          return res;
      }, []));
      return result;
  }, []);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get all the `tr` inside a `table` (having id `table1`) by doing

```
var tableObj = document.getElementById( "table1" );
var arr = [];
var allTRs = tableObj.getElementsByTagName( "tr" );
for ( var trCounter = 0; trCounter < allTRs.length; trCounter++ )
{
   var tmpArr = [];
   var allTDsInTR = allTRs[ trCounter ].getElementsByTagName( "td" );
   for ( var tdCounter = 0; tdCounter < allTDsInTR.length; tdCounter++ )
   {
      tmpArr.push( allTDsInTR[ tdCounter ].innerHTML );
   }
   arr.push( tmpArr );
}
console.log( arr );
```

Comment: Thank you, will try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Run a for loop through the rows and the fields:

```
var array = [];
var table = document.querySelector("table tbody");
var rows = table.children;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var fields = rows[i].children;
  var rowArray = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
    rowArray.push(fields[j].innerHTML);
  }
  array.push(rowArray);
}
console.log(array);
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jsjvm0/).