# Update HTML table (user input) to Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to append the HTML table (user input) to Google Sheets. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650581/transfer-a-html-table-user-input-to-google-sheets) but the solution did not work for me. I've enabled Google Sheets API in Apps Script.
I can use appendrow to update each single row per click, but I look forward to appending the whole table with a single click.

HTML front end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Current Light Type</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="p1" size="25"></td>
    <td>      
       <select id="l1">
         <option>2D</option>
         <option>Donwlight</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="q1" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="p2" size="25"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="l2">
        <option>2D</option>
        <option>Donwlight</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="q2" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  </table> 
    <div>
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
      <script>
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",parse_to_backend);
      function parse_to_backend(){
        let table = document.getElementById("t01").outerHTML;
        google.script.run.pasteHtml(table);
        document.getElementById("p1").value="";
        document.getElementById("l1").value="";
        document.getElementById("q1").value="";
       };
       </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS backend

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
}

function pasteHtml(table) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d...";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var req = {
    requests: [
      {
        pasteData: {
          html: true,
          data: table,
          coordinate: {
            sheetId: ws,
            rowIndex: 0,
            columnIndex: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ws);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. There are two critical things that you didn't maintain from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650581/transfer-a-html-table-user-input-to-google-sheets) you referenced.

1. The value for `sheetId` needs to be the sheet's ID, not the sheet `ws`
2. The `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate()` call expects the spreadsheet ID, not the spreadsheet itself.

```
function pasteHtml(table) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d...";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var req = {
    requests: [
      {
        pasteData: {
          html: true,
          data: table,
          coordinate: {
            sheetId: ws.getSheetId(), // Pass the sheet ID
            rowIndex: 0,
            columnIndex: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ss.getId());  // Pass the spreadsheet ID
}
```

Now, you're going to have some other issues because of the way that you're extracting the table in your front end code (because it's actually inputs within a table), but this works. If you have other questions about how to extract the table/input data, please post another question and add the javascript tag so others can help you with it.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, Diego. It works now, and you are right that I am facing another issue. I will need to spend more time with javascript..

Comment: @JenniferLe Great. If do post another question, please share it and I'll take a look. In the meantime, if you feel it appropriate, please mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Using doGet and doPost functions with Html forms the problem gets very simplified:

JS Backend

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {
  var url = "YOUR_SPREAD_SHEET_URL";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var params = e.parameter;  
  ws.appendRow([params.p1, params.l1, params.q1]);
  ws.appendRow([params.p2, params.l2, params.q2]);
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
}
```

HTML Front

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="PASTE_YOUR_WEBAPP_LINK_HERE" method="post"> 
  <table id="t01">
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Current Light Type</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="p1" id="p1" size="25"></td>
      <td><select name="l1" id="l1"><option>2D</option><option>Donwlight</option></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="q1" id="q1" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="p2" id="p2" size="25"></td>
      <td><select name="l2" id="l2"><option>2D</option><option>Donwlight</option></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="q2" id="q2" size="25"></td>
      <td><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
  </form>
  <div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

For some documentation on `doPost` and `doGet` functions check:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web