# How to append an html table to a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This script sends the data content of an html table to a Google Sheet.

But I now need it to append the data to the next available row.

I've used `appendRow()` in many cases, but I'm not sure of the syntax in this particular case.

```
function pasteRequisicaoHtml(table) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J_7GZ1C7pgHuRsdfsdfsdfsdf");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5').getSheetId();
  var req = {
    requests: [
      {
        pasteData: {
          html: true,
          data: table,
          coordinate: {
            sheetId: sheet,
            rowIndex: 2,
            columnIndex: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ss.getId());
}
```

[image: spreadsheet sample]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer a HTML table (user input) to google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650581/transfer-a-html-table-user-input-to-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put a HTML table to "the next available row" using Sheets API with Google Apps Script as appending.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In your case, you can use both Sheets API and Spreadsheet service. Using this, in order to append the table using Sheets API, you can use `getLastRow()` of Spreadsheet service. And please use the value retrieved by `getLastRow()` to `rowIndex`.

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function pasteRequisicaoHtml(table) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J_7GZ1C7pgHuRsdfsdfsdfsdf");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');  // Modified
  var req = {
    requests: [{
      pasteData: {
        html: true,
        data: table,
        coordinate: {
          sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),  // Modified
          rowIndex: sheet.getLastRow(),  // Modified
          columnIndex: 0,
        },
      },
    }, ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [GridCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other?hl=en#GridCoordinate)

### Added:

In this sample script, the header row is deleted after the table is append. In this case, it supposes that the header row is one row.

```
function pasteRequisicaoHtml(table) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J_7GZ1C7pgHuRsdfsdfsdfsdf");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');  // Modified
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  // Added
  var req = {
    requests: [{
      pasteData: {
        html: true,
        data: table,
        coordinate: {
          sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),  // Modified
          rowIndex: lastRow,  // Modified
          columnIndex: 0,
        },
      },
    }, ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ss.getId());
  sheet.deleteRow(lastRow + 1);  // Added
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the the information, it works. What can I do so that the header row is not included?

Comment: @user2916405 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, in this case, in order to remove the header row, it is required to modify `table` before the table is put or remove the header row after the table was put. But I'm not sure about the value of your `table`. So I would like to propose the latter method. Could you please confirm my updated question? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That's awesome ... That did the trick, it work perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: @user2916405 Thank you for your response.