# Google Sheets Script. getDisplayValues adds Leading Space

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, text-formatting

## [Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pF2y7EtFrENhPIY-k1BtfuPe2WcNR-aw4CyX3rd-kBU/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Users add new values by copying them from an external source.
It creates a visual effect of a small leading space.
Usual formulas can delete this space:

`=""&A1"`

↑ will produce the correct result.

### Problem

when I use:

```
function display(rA1) {
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rA1);
  return r.getDisplayValues();
}
```

The result will include leading spaces

`Test1` →   `Test1`

I cannot delete this format from my original sheet/range: if I click [Ctrl]+[\].

UPD1. Possible to copy and paste Format only.

Comment: `I cannot delete this format from my original sheet/range.` Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the range has a number format:

```
_-* #,##0.00\ _₽_-;\-* #,##0.00\ _₽_-;_-* "-"??\ _₽_-;_-@
```

Ignoring numbers formats, the text format is

```
_-@
```

Where, `_` according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) means

> `_`:Skips the next character and renders a space. This is used to line up number formats where the negative value is surrounded by parenthesis.

Formulas like `TEXT` and scripts using `range.getDisplayValues()` can  directly retrieve the formatted value:

```
=LEN(TEXT("Text1", "_-* #,##0.00\ _₽_-;\-* #,##0.00\ _₽_-;_-* ""-""??\ _₽_-;_-@"))//6
```

##### Note:

Formats, even if you did not apply it directly, the html data from the clipboard maybe directly converted to  number formats by sheets application(Sheets api can also do [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55653038/))

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant. But I don't get documentation example: `[Blue]#,##0;[Red]#,##0;[Green]0.0;[Magenta]_(@_)` shouldn't Magenta be rendered with spaces in this case? `MyText` is displayed without any spaces it's a bit misleading

Comment: @Kos What makes you think it is displayed without spaces?Or Do you mean it is displayed without spaces in the documentation?

Comment: latter, so documentation itself is not useful without trying and see that it's actually spaced

Comment: @Kos You're right. I guess you can send documentation feedback on the top of that page.

Comment: just sent the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason did not come to my mind as I did not often use number formats for text. Changed my sample number format to `0;0;0;_-@` in order to simplify the case.