# send html table data to google sheet via apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

trying to get the cell values from html table and send them to google sheet via apps script:

index.html:

```
     var values = [];
     $("td").each(function(){
       values.push($(this).text());
     });
      
alert(values);  // i can see the array in the alert.

      google.script.run.addRows(values);
    }
```

code.gs:

```
function addRows(values) {
  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('newdata');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

i got an error in the console uncaught addRows, it seems that the array is not detected on the server side, can anyone help
thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650581/transfer-a-html-table-user-input-to-google-sheets/55653038#55653038

Comment: @TheMaster your solution is perfect! but what about the speed of using sheets API vs direct call function to apps script? each call upload about 100rows - 30 cols values together so is Sheets API faster or slower than direct apps script? appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Sheets API is faster. You can check benchmarks by @Tanaike. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details or search his posts here in SO. Having said that, batch all the calls in a single upload. That'll be the fastest way to do this.

Comment: The problem is the array you pass into.  It should be 2d array [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]. Create an array and make a unit test on the addRow() function.  You should be able to resolve this function

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me

gs:

```
function showSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var evaluatHTML = html.evaluate().setTitle('Sidebar')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(evaluatHTML)
};

function addRows(values) {
  Browser.msgBox(values)
}
```

html:

```
  <script>
    function ok(){
     var values = [];
     $("td").each(function(){
       values.push($(this).text());
     });
      
      alert(values);  // i can see the array in the alert.

      google.script.run.addRows(values);
    }
  </script>
```

note that you have to transform the result in a 2D Array, for instance

```
function addRows(values) {
  var tab = [values]
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, tab.length, tab[0].length).setValues(tab)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var values = [];
 $("td").each(function(){
   values.push($(this).text());
 });
 var finalarray =  [[values]]
```

// this will be a 1 row to append