# Adding an html element directly into google sheets cell using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to add an html element directly into google sheets cells using google apps script? I have a tasks list in my minitask.html that I would like to add into my google sheet. I have a large merged cell where I would like to add the element (B39:I71). I haven't been able to find a way to add it directly into my merged cell.

The best solution I have found that gets the task list somewhat on to my sheet is by adding a sidebar of the element.

```html
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Tasks')
      .addItem('Mini Tasks', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('minitask')
      .setTitle('Mini Tasks');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: If you mean one that will be rendered, then the answer is no.  But you could add the the value with sheet.getRange().setValue()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650581 (not a single cell)